# Idiom for "totally watered down"

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there an idiom in English for cases where something is so watered down (figuratively or literally) to the point there is no substance left, just the "bare" water?

Comment: Homeopathed....

Comment: People do use "totally" as an intensifier, often in circumstances where totality is out of the question - e.g. *I was totally exhausted*. Presumably that would mean "dead".

Comment: Watering something down can never, by itself, make it disappear. For nothing but water to be left, some other process would have to be involved, such as distillation.

Comment: 'Hyperattenuated' already has a useful sense.

Comment: Obligitory [Monty Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbxfFOdp-bY)  Not safe for work.

Answer (score 1):

Something may be *faded out*, literally or figuratively.

> **fade out** 1. PHRASAL VERB
>
> When something fades out, it slowly becomes less noticeable or less
>   important until it disappears completely. [[Collins CoBuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/fade-out)]

.........

> **fade out** ...
>
> to diminish and go away altogether.  [[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of
>   American Idioms and Phrasal
>   Verbs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fade+out)]

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/fade-out) licenses the transitive usage:

> **fade out**  [PHRASAL VERB] intransitive/transitive ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, "Homeopathed" isn't that far off.  In theory a "homeopathic" preparation is one where the original drug/herb/whatever is so diluted that there may not even be a single molecule of the stuff in the resulting preparation.  The argument is that the water "remembers" the presence of the stuff, even after it's gone.

Comment: But the verb doesn't exist. In almost 71 years in the American Southwest, there's been a drought of 'homeopathed'.

Answer (score -1):

You've so phrased your question that it conveys more than one interpretation. In Chemestry you might be looking for the word **"solution"** or **"dissolved"**?

> [solution](https://quizlet.com/120207931/solution-flash-cards/) a liquid mixture in which the minor component (the solute) is uniformly distributed within the major component (the solvent).
>
> [dissolve](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dissolve) (with reference to a solid) become or cause to become incorporated into a liquid so as to form a solution.

and, therefore, you often see only the major component.

Comment: A solution of something can be highly concentrated; the OP seems to be seeking a term for a very weak solution.